# Windows 7 Home Premium OA to Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop which had a Windows Home Premium OA version and I cannot find the ISO anywhere on the internet. This way I'm unable to get a genuine version for my laptop.

However, maybe there's some hope left because I also bought a Windows 7 Anytime **upgrade key** from Windows Home Premium to Windows 7 Professional.
Can I use this key without having a genuine **activated** version of Windows Home Premium (as it's a paid update?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just DON'T connect to the internet when you put in the upgrade key.